# how to count the number of folders in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, directory

How to count the number of directories on the desktop?
I get only a list of folders, but I need only the number of folders and I absolutely don't understand how to do it! :(

P.S. NOT files, ONLY folders

thank you!

Comment: How do you get the list of directories? Please [edit] the question to show what you currently have.

Answer (score 5):

try:

`ls -d ./* |wc`

`ls -d ./*` should give you a list of directories and `wc` Count it

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) to count the lines of output after getting the list of folders would be one option. Assuming your operation outputs one line per folder. As an example: `cat myfile.txt | wc -l`

In order to only find the folders you could use something like [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) in a fashion like this: `find . -type d`